# set Background Image to UITableView Section Header

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've searched online and on stackoverflow but couldn't find one good answer how to do it.
I've read about

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`
```

but there's nothing there that can help me.

The closest thing to an image background for the header there is:

```
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackground.png"]];
```

but it shows the picture as a pattern with no way controlling its size.

Comment: "but there's nothing there that can help me." - why not? What unexpected result you get when you implement the first method?

Comment: Nothing is unexpected. I can change the section header font, color etc' but can't use an image as the section header background.

Comment: @MikaStem Have you read some documentation? `UIImage` is not a subclass of `UIView`, so that's natural. The class you're looking for is called `UIImageView`.

Comment: Funny that there are no answers for 7 minutes, then I point out the solution in a comment, then there are suddenly two answers within 30 secs. Seems legit...

Comment: So why not writing an answer instead of a comment then? :)

Comment: lazyness :P (I hit the rep cap for today)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set the image as section header use:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginHeader.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,100);

    return imageView;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: That works but I'm already returning from this method `UIView` instance that includes my label alinement, font etc'. How can I return the image and still keep the label?

Comment: add label as the subview of UIImageView

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background colour to a pattern with image:

```
headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. In the method `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` you will need to simply instantiate a `UIImageView` with an image, set the frame for the imageView object and return the imageView object.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];

    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:1.0f];
    headerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    UILabel* headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,headerView.frame.size.height-40, tableView.frame.size.width - 5, 30)];

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22.0];
    headerLabel.text = @"yourText";
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    UIImageView *headerImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:headerView.frame];


    headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.jpg"]];
    headerImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [headerImage setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [headerView addSubview:headerImage];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: You need to write a bit, what your code is doing and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks Thanks , My code is for to set an image n text to section header , it does best align to image.